# Either Ubuntu via Displayport or Windows via HDMI?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 17.10, amd-graphics

It feels like a catch-22. After I installed a grub2 dual boot on my son's new computer (with a Radeon RX 560 graphics card), I can only access either Windows or Ubuntu 17.10, depending on the connection I use.

An **HDMI** connection allows me to choose an os from grub menu and gives me access to Windows. If I try to access Ubuntu, I get a distorted screen similar to the one linked in this [AU question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970850/ubuntu-17-10-radeon-rx-560-graphics-card). I can, however, access Ubuntu in recovery mode (without noticing any differences from regular Ubuntu, except for the cumbersome way of accessing it). I already put `GRUB_GFXMODE="1920x1080"` in the grub settings, to no avail unfortunately.

A **Displayport** connection lets me access Ubuntu without any problems, but doesn't show the grub menu and subsequently blocks access to Windows.

Any ideas how I could use one cable and have easy access to both os's?

Comment: This issue was solved with Ubuntu 18.04 (or, to be more specific) with Linux kernel 4.15).